# Нету ссылки в HTML

Tags: python, html, парсер, selenium

**Сайт:** https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru/search/index

По информации о залогодателе  -->  *Ввести любую фамилию и имя  -->  НАЙТИ
[image: Ссылка тут]

Мне нужно получить эту ссылку. Я, чтобы зайти на сайт, использую **selenium**. Проблема, что в коде HTML этой ссылки нет, где она и как её достать?

```
<td><span class="notification">2021-005-659097-764</span> <br> <span class="notification">История изменений</span></td>
```

Comment: Мб вы проверяли, когда сайт не закончил прогрузку...

Comment: похоже, что там используется `JS`.